# Angular 10: Styles.css not loading into Index.html

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-json

I've added one html element inside my `index.html` file and now I want to add some styling on it. I have written the style code inside `styles.css` file but it is not reflecting on `index.html` element.

Here is the code:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Angular App</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/x-icon"
      href="https://icons.com/emoj-symbol-30763.png"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root>
      <h2 class="loading-head">Loading .........</h2>
    </app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Styles.css**

```
.loading-head { color: red; }
```

**angular.json**

```
  "styles": [
     "src/theme.less",
     "src/styles.css"
  ],
```

**File Structure**

```
/src/
  --index.html
  --styles.css
/
  --angular.json
```

**Angular Version**

```
Angular CLI: 10.1.1
Node: 14.10.1
```

I'm not able to figure out what & where I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Content of app-root is loaded before angular bootstrap and removed after it bootstraps to achieve styles on loader you must either insert in line css or use different stylesheet and load it manually in index.html

Comment: glad to help :)